# Error when create new Search services Application

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, searchserviceapplication

I got error when create Search service Application, The Server is throwing log;

Errors were encountered during the configuration of the Search Service Application.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the
>   current state of the object. at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDatabase.Update() at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchDatabase.BaseUpdate()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchDatabase.CreateCleanDatabase[T](String
>   searchApplicationName, ISearchDatabaseParameters databaseParameters)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.Create(String
>   name, SearchQueryAndSiteSettingsService service,
>   SPIisWebServiceApplicationPool applicationPool,
>   SPIisWebServiceApplicationPool adminApplicationPool,
>   ISearchDatabaseParameters adminDBParameters, ISearchDatabaseParameters
>   searchSettingsDBParameters, IEnumerable`1 crawlStoreDBsParameters,
>   IEnumerable`1 analyticsStoreDBsParameters, IEnumerable`1
>   linksStoreDBsParameters, SPPartitionOptions partitionOptions, Boolean
>   cloudIndex) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.Create(String
>   name, SearchQueryAndSiteSettingsService service,
>   SPIisWebServiceApplicationPool applicationPool,
>   SPIisWebServiceApplicationPool adminApplicationPool,
>   ISearchDatabaseParameters adminDBParameters, ISearchDatabaseParameters
>   searchSettingsDBParameters, IEnumerable`1 crawlStoreDBsParameters,
>   IEnumerable`1 analyticsStoreDBsParameters, IEnumerable`1
>   linksStoreDBsParameters, SPPartitionOptions partitionOptions, Boolean
>   cloudIndex) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchService.CreateApplication(String
>   name, ISearchDatabaseParameters adminDBParameters,
>   ISearchDatabaseParameters searchSettingsDBParameters, IEnumerable`1
>   crawlStoreDBParameters, IEnumerable`1
>   analyticsReportingStoreDBParameters, IEnumerable`1
>   linksStoreDBParameters, SPIisWebServiceApplicationPool
>   applicationPool, SPIisWebServiceApplicationPool adminApplicationPool,
>   SPPartitionOptions partitionOptions, Boolean cloudIndex)at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchService.CreateApplicationWithDefaultTopology(String
>   name, Boolean cloudIndex, SPIisWebServiceApplicationPool
>   applicationPool, SPIisWebServiceApplicationPool
>   searchAdminApplicationPool) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchConfigWizard.CreateSearchApp()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchConfigWizard.ProvisionSearchServiceApplication()at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchConfigurationJobDefinition.ExecuteTimerJob()
>   12/3/2019 1:23:19 AM.

I using SP 2016

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot your issue as following:

1. Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is a member of the Farm Administrators group for the farm.
2. Make sure farm admin account have dbcreator and securityadmin permission.
3. Go to services.msc, check if "SharePoint Search Host Controller", "SharePoint Server Search 16" and "SharePoint Timer Service" are running and logon as farm admin account.
   Run SharePoint Product Configuration wizard and check again.
4. If the issue exists, install the latest CU on every SharePoint Server and check the result.